# Replacing 2 words with each other while ignore case, PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, case

I'm trying to replace 2 words in a string with each other, while ignoring their cases, but I can't seem to figure out a way to make it work right. Please take a look at my code:

```
$text = "you and me";

$text = str_ireplace("you","me",$text);
//$text is "me and me";  
$text = str_ireplace("me","you",$text);
//$text is "you and you";
```

**Expected result:** "me and you";

**Actual result:** "you and you";

Edit: That actual doesn't include ignoring cases.

Comment: I think this question is not duplicate because author requires case insensitive search, anyway I added an answer to related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy, just use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php):

```
$text = "YoU and mE";
$from = array('you', 'me', '__TMP__');
$to   = array('__TMP__', 'you', 'me');
$text = str_ireplace($from, $to, $text);
```

Comment: Does that ignore case like str_ireplace?

Comment: It gave me an internet web error.

Comment: @jessica I updated example

Answer (score 0):

Check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

```
$trans = array("you" => "me", "me" => "you");
echo strtr("you and me", $trans);
```

Comment: That doesn't work for multicase string.

Comment: You are right, this should be your friend

    str_ireplace(array_keys($replace_pairs), array_values($replace_pairs), $str);